# Compare a dictionary with list of dictionaries and return index from the list which has higher value than the separate dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and a separate dictionary having the same keys and only the values are different. For example the list of dictionaries look like this:

```
[{'A': 0.102, 'B': 0.568, 'C': 0.33}, {'A': 0.026, 'B': 0.590, 'C': 0.382}, {'A': 0.005, 'B': 0.857, 'C': 0.137}, {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.962, 'C': 0.036}, {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.991, 'C': 0.008}]
```

and the separate dictionary looks like this:

```
{'A': 0.005, 'B': 0.956, 'C': 0.038}
```

I want to compare the separate dictionary with the list of dictionaries and return the index from the list which has higher value than the separate dictionary. In this example, the indices would be 3, 4 as the dictionary in indices 3 and 4 has a higher value for key `'B'` since `'B'` has the highest value in the separate dictionary.

Any ideas on how I should I proceed the problem?

Comment: why don't return `index=0` the key="A" & "C" have higher value.

Comment: I edited the question. Here key 'B' is chosen as it has the highest value in the separate dictionary. The key with the highest value in the separate dictionary would be chosen and compared with the list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` for finding index of max value:

```
org = [
    {'A': 0.102, 'B': 0.568, 'C': 0.33}, 
    {'A': 0.026, 'B': 0.590, 'C': 0.382}, 
    {'A': 0.005, 'B': 0.857, 'C': 0.137}, 
    {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.962, 'C': 0.036}, 
    {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.991, 'C': 0.008}
] 

com = {'A': 0.005, 'B': 0.956, 'C': 0.038}

def fnd_index(org, com):
    key_max, val_max = max(com.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print('key_max:', key_max)
    print('val_max:', val_max)
    res = []
    for idx, dct in enumerate(org):
        if dct[key_max] > val_max:
            res.append(idx)
    return res


res = fnd_index(org, com)
print('result:', res)
```

Output:

```
key_max: B
val_max: 0.956
result: [3, 4]
```

Comment: As mentioned by @SergFSM, the indices 3 and 4 should be returned. I corrected the question and mentioning here for clarification.

Comment: Yes that's correct now.

Comment: @PritamDeka, edited the answer, I think you want this, you want to find max value and key of the max,  then check the original dict and return index base key_max.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure that it should be only index 4?

```
dict_list = [{'A': 0.102, 'B': 0.568, 'C': 0.33}, 
             {'A': 0.026, 'B': 0.590, 'C': 0.382}, 
             {'A': 0.005, 'B': 0.857, 'C': 0.137}, 
             {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.962, 'C': 0.036}, 
             {'A': 0.0, 'B': 0.991, 'C': 0.008}] 

d = {'A': 0.005, 'B': 0.956, 'C': 0.038}

max_val = max(d.values())
idxmax = [i for i,j in enumerate(dict_list) if max(j.values()) > max_val]

print(idxmax)  # [3, 4]
```

Comment: You are right. I have edited the question accordingly.